# Installing Ubuntu in a new computer

Tags: ubuntu, installation, operating-systems

I recently purchased a ThinkServer TS140 (Intel i3-4130; 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD). It comes without any installed OS or drivers.

How do I install the Ubuntu OS in this computer? I tried burning the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO file onto a DVD and booting from the DVD, but that did not work.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: check bios is the CD/DVD higher in order than the hdd/ssd ? if not make it so and retry  (the blue thinkadvantage button on most things thinkpad should be all that is needed to get you access to BIOS to check.

Comment: A few things.  1: "Did not work" is not a diagnosis.  Please be specific in the problem.  2: For a server, you'll probably want a server OS, so make sure you have that (unless you know for sure you don't want the server variant).  3: as said above, check the bios and make sure you actually are booting from the DVD.  4: When you burned the image, did you actually BURN THE IMAGE?  Or did you just burn the iso FILE as raw data?  To find out, put the dvd in another machine.  if it's just one iso file, you did it wrong.  If it's a bunch of files and folders, you probably did it right.